# Name of a conjecture

Tags: number-theory

I would like to know the name of the following conjecture: 
If $2^n$ and $3^n$ are both integers, must $n$ be an integer?

A friend mentioned that this was an unsolved problem. However, I am unable to find anything about this online.

Comment: try $n=\log_2 3=1.584962501$  Or are you saying that $2^n,3^n$ have to both be integers?

Comment: @lulu Yes, this seems to be the intent of the question

Comment: @Peter  That makes sense.  Looks hard...at least I have no immediate ideas.

Comment: This is an unsovled problem. https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-deceptively-simple-looking-math-problems.